# "Could not load file or assembly" error when installing Google.api.customsearch.v1 client library

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I am trying to install *Google.api.customsearch.v1 client library* from *Nuget* but I get this error when I try to run my asp.net website.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have discovered stackoverflow for such issue, but non of them resolved my problem. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem by updating Newtonsoft.Json package. Run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```